# Flagging WHYT on deleted posts

Tags: discussion, comment, flagging, deleted-questions, badges

## Background info

The comment ["what have you tried" has been banned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172760/259305) on the SE network, and it's removable by a single flag.

## Motivation

The [Marshal](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/132?page=1) badge is awarded to users who have raised 500 helpful flags.  Flags that trigger automatic removal of a WHYT-comment count immediately towards the total number of helpful flags.

## Question

If a WHYT-comment is found in a deleted post, can one still flag it?

[image]

Image source: [*One-to-one functions and Onto functions question (deleted)*](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3949210/290189)

Comment: The motivation seems a bit dubious to me. I don't see the point in flagging those comments on (old) deleted posts, unless undeletion is planned.

Comment: what have you tried

Comment: related, falsifies claim : https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147161/

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Yes, this four-word comment can be automatically removed using either "it's unfriendly or unkind"
or "it's no longer needed".  I haven't tested, and I won't test the other two options as the two options in the middle are the most appropriate ones.

[image]

After flagging, the four-word comment disappeared.

[image]

[image]